# Cannot set AndroidDriver. AndroidUIAutomator2 cannot start a new session, with response code 500

Tags: java, appium, android-uiautomator

I'm using Appium 2.0.0-beta.61 and AndroidUiAutomator2, and when I try to start the Android driver, it fails, returning Response Code 500. I tried removing the Appium server app from the device and using a different device like other threads suggested but it doesn't help.

Increasing the *uiautomator2ServerLaunchTimeout* also didn't help.

```
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@9c56 (e03bdf49)] The instrumentation process cannot be initialized within 120000ms timeout. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output. You could also try to increase the value of 'uiautomator2ServerLaunchTimeout' capability
10:31:32 SamsungS8Plus [ERROR] Failed to set driver. Closing Appium to prevent it from staying open after test fail. Please check exception below:
10:31:32 SamsungS8Plus [ERROR] Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized within 120000ms timeout. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output. You could also try to increase the value of 'uiautomator2ServerLaunchTimeout' capability 
Host info: host: 'INV-15330', ip: '192.168.67.232'
Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:adbPort=5037, appium:systemPort=8301, appium:newCommandTimeout=180, appium:androidInstallTimeout=120000, appium:automationName=UIAutomator2, appium:udid=712KPRW1234990, appium:uiautomator2ServerLaunchTimeout=120000, appium:autoGrantPermissions=true, appium:remoteAdbHost=localhost, appium:appActivity=com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity, platformName=ANDROID, appium:app=C:\Users\Gre\Documents\htautomation\games\Puzzle\Android\Puzzle.apk, appium:uiautomator2ServerInstallTimeout=120000}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {appium:adbPort: 5037, appium:androidInstallTimeout: 120000, appium:app: C:\Users\Gre\Doc..., appium:appActivity: com.unity3d.player.UnityPla..., appium:autoGrantPermissions: true, appium:automationName: UIAutomator2, appium:newCommandTimeout: 180, appium:remoteAdbHost: localhost, appium:systemPort: 8301, appium:udid: 712KPRW1234990, appium:uiautomator2ServerInstallTimeout: 120000, appium:uiautomator2ServerLaunchTimeout: 120000, platformName: ANDROID}}]
Capabilities {appium:adbPort: 5037, appium:androidInstallTimeout: 120000, appium:app: C:\Users\Gre\Doc..., appium:appActivity: com.unity3d.player.UnityPla..., appium:autoGrantPermissions: true, appium:automationName: UIAutomator2, appium:newCommandTimeout: 180, appium:remoteAdbHost: localhost, appium:systemPort: 8301, appium:udid: 712KPRW1234990, appium:uiautomator2ServerInstallTimeout: 120000, appium:uiautomator2ServerLaunchTimeout: 120000, platformName: ANDROID}
```

```
AppiumServiceBuilder builder;
        builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder()
                .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL, "error")
                .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.ALLOW_INSECURE, "adb_screen_streaming, chromedriver_autodownload")
                .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1")
                .usingPort(getAppiumServerFromSystemEnv());

        server = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
        server.start();
```

```
try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver(server.getUrl(), options);
        } catch (org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException e) {
            loggerUtils.log(LoggerLevel.ERROR,"[HTA] Failed to set driver. Closing Appium to prevent it from staying open after test fail. Please check exception below:");
            loggerUtils.log(LoggerLevel.ERROR, e.getMessage());
            closeAppiumServer();
        }
```

I wanted to launch an android application on a real device. Using Appium2 and AndroidUiAutomator2. The AndroidDriver cannot be initialized, timeout happens and returns Response code 500.

Comment: Can you please try to increase the `uiautomator2ServerLaunchTimeout` time to `15000` or more as per observed from the logs you shared?

Comment: @BipinKumarChaurasia Hi, I did that and it didn't help. I increased it to as much as `240000`. It still fails, just takes more time before app timeouts

Comment: Which real mobile device are you using? Can you please share the model information along with android OS version?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a resolution to my problem. I used

```
UiAutomator2Options.setRemoteAdbHost("localhost")
```

and that's where the issue was. I don't really know why, as "localhost" is the default value. But changing it to

```
UiAutomator2Options.setRemoteAdbHost("127.0.0.1")
```

fixed the issue for me. The session is correctly started.